# Degenerate arrows/points in StreamPlot

Tags: plotting, version-12.1

Drawing a `StreamPlot` of a linear dynamical system:

```
A = {{9, -15}, {7, -9}};
StreamPlot[A.{x, y}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, StreamPoints -> Coarse]
```

[image]

results in a few colinear points inside the ellipse. I guess they are some degenerate arrows, but it looks very confusing, so how to get rid of those? (They stay there when `StreamPoints -> Medium` as well, although less abundant.)

```
$Version
```

> "12.1.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete short arrows?:

```
A = {{9, -15}, {7, -9}};
StreamPlot[A . {x, y}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  StreamPoints -> Coarse] /. 
 Arrow[a_] /; Total[Norm /@ Differences[a]] < 0.1 :> {}
```

[image]

Comment: Note to editor(s): `Norm[Differences[a]]` is a matrix norm of an $(n-1) \times 2$ of the difference vectors of the coordinates of the $n$ points of each arrow, the meaning of which escapes me; `Total[Norm /@ Differences[a]]` gives the length of the arrow. A slightly simpler formulation would be `ArcLength[Line@a]`.  It would be really nice if `ArcLength` worked with `Arrow`, but it does not.

Comment: `Norm[Differences[a]]` works in this code.

Comment: @rhomboidRhipper It implements a selection criterion that, luckily, *happens* to work, but it's the wrong idea and not equivalent. It would result in the deletion of `a = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0., 0.5, 0.01}];`, which would be wrong, since `Arrow[a]` makes a rather long arrow. The difference above if `< 0.1` is changed to `< 0.2` is evident, too.

Answer (score 3):

Set the `aratio` and `npts` in `SteamScale` maybe one method.

```
A = {{9, -15}, {7, -9}};
StreamPlot[A . {x, y}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, StreamPoints -> Coarse,
  StreamScale -> {Automatic, 2, .01, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: Ingenious, but changing anything, like `AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio`, makes the arrows display ugly, and then altering `StreamScale` make the degenerate arrows appear again.